# How can I detect if a website is built with React?

Tags: reactjs

When I browse to any website on the public world wide web, for example [CarGurus Canada](https://ca.cargurus.com/), how can I detect is this website is built using [React](https://reactjs.org/)?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `react-dev-tools` would be able to show you this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if a web application is using ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817526/how-to-tell-if-a-web-application-is-using-reactjs)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `React Developer Tools` [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi). React's logo will light up everytime you visit a site built in React. Here's how it looks like in the site you've mentioned

[image]

and on SO

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use this awesome [gist](https://gist.github.com/rambabusaravanan/1d594bd8d1c3153bc8367753b17d074b)

```
// Pase these lines into website's console ( Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + I )

if(!!window.React ||
   !!document.querySelector('[data-reactroot], [data-reactid]'))
  console.log('React.js');

if(!!window.angular ||
   !!document.querySelector('.ng-binding, [ng-app], [data-ng-app], [ng-controller], [data-ng-controller], [ng-repeat], [data-ng-repeat]') ||
   !!document.querySelector('script[src*="angular.js"], script[src*="angular.min.js"]'))
  console.log('Angular.js');

if(!!window.Backbone) console.log('Backbone.js');
if(!!window.Ember) console.log('Ember.js');
if(!!window.Vue) console.log('Vue.js');
if(!!window.Meteor) console.log('Meteor.js');
if(!!window.Zepto) console.log('Zepto.js');
if(!!window.jQuery) console.log('jQuery.js');
```

or use [BuiltWith](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith/hleikeoncmpohnmdkkagcbppgdecoiak?hl=en) chrome extension

Comment: The React one doesn't work for a simple react app created by `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: this awesome gist doesn't work, I test it on a reactjs webpage but none of `if`s works.

Comment: I can also confirm that it doens't work. (It's quite obvious why it doesn't work...)

Comment: Doesn't work indeed. Checked too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of extensions available to detect this. Below are the links to their chrome extension pages:

- [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer-technology-pro/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg/related) - Most downloaded and reviewed
- [WhatRuns](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatruns/cmkdbmfndkfgebldhnkbfhlneefdaaip)
- [BuiltWith Technology Profiler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn/)