# Detect React with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a library author, I'd like to know whether my library is being used with React or with some other UI framework (Vue, Svelte, ...).

Is there a way to detect whether React's code was loaded?

The following Stack Overflow answers don't answer this question because they only work using the developer console. (Whereas I want to detect React from the perspective of a JavaScript library.)

- [How to tell if a web application is using ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817526/how-to-tell-if-a-web-application-is-using-reactjs)
- [How can I detect if a website is built with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133928/how-can-i-detect-if-a-website-is-built-with-react)

Context: I'm building [vite-plugin-ssr](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/). (It's like Next.js/Nuxt but as a do-one-thing-do-it-well Vite plugin.)

**EDIT**: I need to be able to detect React as soon as React is loaded in the browser, **before** React even renders/hydrates the page. So far, all answers below are detecting React too late.

Comment: the 2nd link you post shows how to do it from vanilla javascript

Comment: That answer from the 2nd link doesn't work. (It assumes a specific framework which will actually never be used in the case for my library.)

Comment: Not 100% reliable since people can try to [turn off dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783620/disable-chrome-react-devtools-for-production/39152804#39152804), but this might be useful: [How does React Developer Tools determine that the webpage is using React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807826/how-does-react-developer-tools-determine-that-the-webpage-is-using-react)

Comment: Embedded in a React APPLICATION, or just used anywhere React lives? We have React components being used in a page that was not itself built using react. We merely include a src link for React and use the DOM to add the element. As such, "React" is available in Global.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I updated the question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @David Fong The accepted answer doesn't work reliably, see its comments. And it actually never works in my specific use case.

Comment: You probably need to register a service worker and intercept the fetch requests for JS assets. From there you can inspect the response and grep it for some indicator of React before returning the normal response to the client. Otherwise I'm not sure how you are going to detect the presence of React in the browser without React already leaving some presence of itself in the DOM.

Comment: @brillout Can you point to which code would be checking for React in https://github.com/brillout/vite-plugin-ssr? Or in case the code doesn't exist yet, where would it more or less live, or what would it be doing with the knowledge of a page having React? It's currently not very obvious how the use case is different from the linked questions.

Comment: @inwerpsel https://github.com/brillout/vite-plugin-ssr/blob/43811ba4dc09b7e9ada46761f085190460b3325e/vite-plugin-ssr/client/router/useClientRouter.ts#L179-L184 As you can see vite-plugin-ssr needs the information whether the user is using React *before* the hydration process even started.

Comment: All that happens with this information in the code is a static warning about the use of `hydrationCanBeAborted`  is produced in the console. Why would this need to happen before hydration starts?

Comment: @inwerpsel See https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/clientRouting > Ctrl-F `hydrationCanBeAborted`. The current implementation and its config is a workaround: ideally vite-plugin-ssr should be able automatically determine whether the user is using React and therefore whether the hydration can be aborted.

Comment: If you have time for it, you can check how React developer tools browser extension is doing it. As it's made by React developers I assume that they will have the best solution for it.

Comment: Can you describe the scenario where the hydration should be aborted? The information of whether it can be aborted is only needed at the point you need to abort, right? So it can at that point evaluate React detection logic, it doesn't have to be before React loaded. Or is there a reason it needs to be determined in advance?

Comment: Imagine a user clicking on a link before the hydration is finished: vite-plugin-ssr can then abort the hydration and render the new page.

Comment: Can't the identification process happen on the backend? Via a simple `require` statement or as a parameter?

Comment: @aifrim That's actually a good idea... although `require` won't work for monorepos with a flat `node_modules/`. But server-side detecting could be easier indeed.

Comment: @brillout I suggest a parameter. Seems like the best solution. Removes detection code, and moves the burden from you to the end-user. And the end-user knows the framework he is using.

Comment: @aifrim Yep, that's what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if a web application is using ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817526/how-to-tell-if-a-web-application-is-using-reactjs)

Answer (score 11):

I've come up with the following solution:

```js
const isReactApp = !!Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll("*")).find((node) => node._reactRootContainer)
```

It works on create-react-app as well as gatsby projects (possible more as I've tested only those so far).

Basically it traverses through all elements and check if the magic `reactRootContainer` attribute is defined on the element.
Consider that the snippet could be very slow on huge pages with lots of DOM nodes.

However, I would generally advise against using this approach as it's likely that the `reactRootContainer` property will change (since it's private) in the near future.

A better approach would be to let the developers who'll use your library tell your library that they are using react (or vue or svelte or x).

Something like:

```
import MyLibrary from '@mylibrary/react';
```

EDIT:
Another approach I've found which could work for most react projects as long as they attach any event handler:

```
// find the reactEvents${....} variable in the document.
!!Object.keys(document).find(key => key.includes('react'))
```

Comment: Interesting trick. Although, if there are a *lot* of DOM elements, that could impact performance?

Comment: Yeah that would definitely impact performance quite bit.

Although once it actually finds the react node it will stop to search it still traverses through the DOM.
 
I've updated my answer with another hacky-way to detect react which does not traverse the DOM.

Comment: This is very similar to the answer I first came up with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73450873/11107541) where I give an optimization to filter by nodes with the `id` attribute with the caveat that it works only under the assumption that a site will usually give the react root an id to make it easy to initialize.

Comment: The approach added in the edit doesn't seem solid. Anything that added something to do the document containing the string "react" would falsely be picked up.

Comment: You could also check for reactEvents$ instead of react but it's still a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Instead of detecting react on the runtime, you can detect it on the build time.

```
let react: any;
try {
  react = require("react");
  console.log("react detected");
} catch (err) {
  console.log("no react detected");
}
```

Then your hook on the runtime just throws an error when there is no react.

```
export function useMyHook() {
  if (!react) throw new Error("react is undefined");
  const [state, setter] = react.useState();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can detect if an application is using React using this way:

```
const isUsingReact = window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ 
  && window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.size > 0
```

This is the way used by the official extension, so I think it's reliable.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d483463bc86555decb3e8caa18459d1d0f7c0148/packages/react-devtools-extensions/src/main.js#L57

Comment: Unfortunately, React seems to populate `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers` fairly late and `size` is `0` at page load.

Answer (score -1):

The closest i could come up to automatically getting the info (*based on [How to tell if a web application is using ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73450873/128165)*) without continuously scanning the whole DOM is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in the DOM and check for `_reactRootContainer` on the mutated element.

```js
function onReactLoad(callback) {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
    const hasReact =
      const hasReact = mutationList.some(({
        target
      }) => target._reactRootContainer !== undefined);
      
    if (hasReact) {
      callback();
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
  });
}

// usage
onReactLoad(() => {
  console.log('react detected')
});
```