# Using React JS on single pages within larger sites

Tags: reactjs

How do sites use ReactJS on their web pages when the whole site is not built with React?

I was under the impression that if you used ReactJS then the whole site had to be delivered using ReactJS.

So for example, https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/scores-fixtures which is part of the BBC website seems to use React (as per [How to tell if a web application is using ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817526/how-to-tell-if-a-web-application-is-using-reactjs/56817632) ).

Comment: You can load a React app into any element on a page, it's possible to have 1 app running a whole site, or 10 apps on a single page, it's just a matter of how it's built. I'm not sure how to answer this well, but reading the "[getting started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)" docs may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember that react is just plain old Javascript, if you read the documentation you'd know that you can import it even with a  tag or in any way you see fit.

Here's the link to the docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html