# How to know website develop in React or Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frameworks

Same like example of [wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/) i'm developing `script` for just to **identify** which technology framework are using.

So i did with other `e-commerece` & `CMS` but for **react** & **Node** how to identify the same tech is used.

From the source or cookies any identification can we retrive ?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of this react extension to know if the website is in react or not, or in react development or in production.

[React Developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)

if we want to know in code u can use something like:

[stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817526/how-to-tell-if-a-web-application-is-using-reactjs/56817632)